# application restart multiple times on openshift pod and no error logs

Tags: spring-boot, openshift

Trying to deploy my application after upgrading springboot 2.7.13 / spring 5.4/junit 5/gradle 7.2 & tomcat 9.81, but the openshift pod is restarting on loop, there are no error specific to the pod crash, but can see the below log printing continuously for several times before crashing.

```
2023-11-09 06:51:52.261 [main] [DEBUG] o.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase [] - Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarWarResourceSet@222da0] to [STARTED]
2023-11-09 06:51:52.298 [main] [DEBUG] o.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase [] - Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarWarResourceSet@33bea0] to [INITIALIZING]
2023-11-09 06:51:52.327 [main] [DEBUG] o.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase [] - Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarWarResourceSet@33dbea0] to [INITIALIZED]
2023-11-09 06:51:52.379 [main] [DEBUG] o.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase [] - Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarWarResourceSet@33dbea0] to [STARTING_PREP]
2023-11-09 06:51:52.420 [main] [DEBUG] o.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase [] - Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarWarResourceSet@33dbea0] to [STARTING]
2023-11-09 06:51:52.472 [main] [DEBUG] o.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase [] - Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarWarResourceSet@33dbea0] to [STARTED]
2023-11-09 06:51:52.532 [main] [DEBUG] o.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase [] - Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarWarResourceSet@77d9b] to [INITIALIZING]
2023-11-09 06:51:52.615 [main] [DEBUG] o.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase [] - Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarWarResourceSet@77d9b] to [INITIALIZED]
2023-11-09 06:51:52.687 [main] [DEBUG] o.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase [] - Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarWarResourceSet@77d9b] to [STARTING_PREP]
2023-11-09 06:51:52.735 [main] [DEBUG] o.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase [] - Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarWarResourceSet@77d9b] to [STARTING]
```

Comment: Post a describe for the pod, as well as events for the namespace. A pod restarting on loop is just likely to be caused be an OOMkill or failed liveness probe than an actual container error.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion.The pod is restarting with liveness readiness probe failure in the events,  and the curl on probe url shows faulure wiht 137 Error. but the same build is working fien on another common pod. what shoule be done in this case.